# UI info in domain driven design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm implementing DDD in my project and have a model called `event` (as in birthday, party etc).

An event has a start and end date so has a model such as the following:

```
public class Event
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private DateTime _endDate;

    // methods omitted for brevity
}
```

So far, this is fine and I'm happy with it.

Now in the UI the section that shows the start and end date, the user can choose the background colour. This could be added as:

```
public class Event
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private DateTime _endDate;
    private Color _dateColor;
}
```

And this could be repeated many times for each section of the UI (the location section could have a colour, etc).

I feel that the domain shouldn't have UI specific values within it, but then where else could I save this?

I'm also worried about polluting the domain with all these additional fields, so could do something like:

```
public class Event
{
    public EventDates EventDates { get; private set; }
}

public class EventDates
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private DateTime _endDate;
    private Color _dateColor;
}
```

But then feel like things like start/end date shouldn't be on a sub entity, they are core to the actual event.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this with scalability and encapsulation in mind:

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public EventDisplayOptions DisplayOptions { get; set; }
}

public class EventDisplayOptions
{
    public Color DateBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public Color SomeOtherFieldColor {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, is a very neat way of encapsulating it!

Answer (score 0):

- Are all events of a given type i.e birthday or party have same color?
- Is there a need to couple dates and display color in same event ?
- can display color be configured with separate configuration rather than being specified  explicitly in the event?

If colors for different  types of events could be configured completely separately then i suggest to keep display color related information in separate object.